# Get file extension from uploaded file

Tags: java, playframework, apache-commons-fileupload

Here my requirement is to upload the file and to store it in the disk. I have no problem in storing it in disk, but getting the extension of the file. The problem is when I click on upload and processing the file to store in disk, it is saved as a temp file with following name

> "/tmp/multipartBody6238081076014199817asTemporaryFile"

here the file doesn't have an extension. So any of the following libraries doesn't help me get the extension of the file.

```
FileNameUtils.getExtension()

or

Files.getFileExtension(path)
```

I've even tried to get it through it's attributes, but it doesn't have an option to get the file extension.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/**/**/filepath");
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput" class="filestyle"  data-classIcon="icon-plus" data-classButton="btn btn-primary" >
```

Get file object from Play framework:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
FilePart fileInput = body.getFile("fileInput");
File file = fileInput.getFile();
```

Any help to extract file extension is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: File itself should have extension, then only it can be retrieved in Java.Please make sure you have extension while saving.

Comment: The file has an extension while uploading from frontend. But while I get the "File" object from backend (Java), I get the above mentioned temp file. That's the problem.

Comment: In that case, you can attach an extension before saving it to the disk.

Comment: are you using apache common.io + common fileupload ?

Comment: don't let to write temp file and force to write in specific path with your defined name and extentions.

Comment: yeah, I use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to upload file. FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, destDir, true); I write it to my specified directory only. But the thing is, when I get the file from request object (after it is been uploaded from html page), the file is in tmp location already (before I do start upload processing in Java). Hope you understand the situation.

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks for helping so far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. Actually this is of Play framework. I got the file using following code.

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
FilePart fileInput = body.getFile("fileInput");
File file = fileInput.getFile();
```

I tried to get the name of file using this **File** object (which is used to store in a *tmp* location). But I missed to notice that **FilePart** object contains all file details that was uploaded. Then I figured it out.

`fileInput.getFilename()` gives me the uploaded file name with extension. It solves my problem.

Thanks for *Cataclysm* for helping me out. Surely the one he gave is the best answer for other framework like Struts/Spring or core servlets.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Jquery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) in client side.

And at my JS file ,

```
function doUploadPhoto(seq) {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url : 'news/upload.html?s=' + seq,
    sequentialUploads : true,
    disableImageResize : false,
    imageMaxWidth : 1024,
    imageMaxHeight : 1024,
    previewCrop : true,
    dropZone : $("#dropZone"),
    acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    progress : function(e, data) {
        if (data.context) {
            var progress = data.loaded / data.total * 100;
            progress = Math.floor(progress);
            $('.progress').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
            $('.progress').css('display', 'block');
            $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        }
    },
    progressall : function(e, data) {
        var progress = data.loaded / data.total * 100;
        progress = Math.floor(progress);
        $('.progressall').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
        $('.progressall').css('display', 'block');
        $('.allbar').css('width', progress + '%');
        if (progress > 20) {
            $('.allbar').text(progress + '% Completed');
        }
    },
    stop: function (e) {
        return;
    }
});
}
```

Handle your specific request for image upload (I used Spring).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/news/upload.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final void uploadNewsPhoto(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    doUploadNewsPhoto(request, getSessionFileItems(request));
}
```

for upload image

```
public final synchronized String doUploadNewsPhoto(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {

    try {
        List<Map<String, Object>> ret = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                try {
                    // get news sequence for save it's images
                    Long seq = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("s"));
                    Map<String, Object> res = newsPhotoBiz.saveToFile(seq, item, SecuritySession.getLoginUserSeq());

                    res.put("name", item.getName());
                    res.put("size", item.getSize());
                    ret.add(res);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error, can't upload news photo file, name:" + item.getName(), e);
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove files from session because we have a copy of them
        removeSessionFileItems(request);

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("files", ret);
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(json);
        // return to client side about uploaded images info
        return obj.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error, when upload news photo file", e);
        throw new UploadActionException(e);
    }
}
```

for save image

```
public final Map<String, Object> saveToFile(final Long newsSeq, final FileItem item, final Long loginUserSeq)
        throws BusinessException {
    String staticDir = System.getProperty("staticDir");

    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat fmtYMD = new SimpleDateFormat("/yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat fmtHMS = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssS");

    String saveDir = "data/news" + fmtYMD.format(today);
    String format = ".jpg";
    try {
        format = item.getName().substring(item.getName().lastIndexOf("."), item.getName().length());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      format = ".jpg";
    }

    try {
        String fileName = newsSeq + "_" + fmtHMS.format(today) + format;

        NewsPhotoBean bean = new NewsPhotoBean();
        bean.setNewsSeq(newsSeq);
        bean.setFile(saveDir + "/" + fileName);
           // save image infos in database and return it's sequence
        Long photoSeq = newsPhotoService.add(bean, loginUserSeq);

        // Save image in specify location
        String filePath = staticDir + "/" + saveDir;
        FileSupport.saveFile(filePath, fileName, item);

        Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ret.put("seq", newsSeq);
        ret.put("photoSeq", photoSeq);
        ret.put("path", saveDir + "/" + fileName);
        ret.put("ext", format.substring(1));

       //client side may need uploaded images info
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BusinessException("Error occur when save file. newsSeq : " + newsSeq, e);
    }
}
```

for write image

```
// Save Image by FileItem that gets from Image Upload
public static String saveFile(final String filePath, final String fileName, final FileItem item) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.setExecutable(true, false);
    file.setWritable(true, false);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File imageFile = new File(file, fileName);
    item.write(imageFile);
    item.setFieldName(filePath + fileName);

    return item.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is your String variable "format" takes hardcoded ".jpg" or the one from try block? And what name does your FileItem show when you check it through debug? Does it show file name with extension?

Comment: @svjn I didn't hardcoded `.jpg` , just for initialize. You can add this statement in catch block for exception but I think it is not nessary.

Comment: @svjn `Does it show file name with extension?` just try yourself ! I think you may see as uploaded extension. Have useful for you. :-)

Comment: That's what the problem I am getting. My file object doesn't show the extension. It's showing as the tmp file I mentioned in question. If it shows, then your answer is perfect for me. But it doesn't show. :(

Comment: @svjn check this http://puu.sh/93cEr.png , I uploaded png image. you can see **25_162843821.png** . ok ?

Comment: Ya I see it. Client side is just HTML input type file. I don't think the problem is there. It should be the way the play framework works. I've updated the question with the html and play framework code.

Comment: @svjn Would you like to see HTML ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54518/discussion-between-svjn-and-cataclysm).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("input-file"); 
String type=filePart.getContentType();
type="."+type.substring(type.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the extension of a file from servlet upload, your form enctype should be "multipart/form-data"
Example upload form:

```
    <form  action="CheatQuizUpload" method="POST" target="miao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Upload your file<br>
                <input required type="file" name="file">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                <br>
            </form>
```

On the server-side, the parameter name of the file will correspond to the "name" attribute of the input.

```
        //...other request handling code 
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");/*"name" attribute of your input*/
        String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();//full name of file submitted
        String[] fileNameSplit = fileName.split(".");//split between name and extension
        String extension = fileNameSplit[fileNameSplit.length-1];//get the extension part of the file name
```