# validation on file upload in servlets and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am uploading images (png ,jpeg,gif) to the server ,I have made validation on client side using js for

1-File size 
2-File type 
But how to achieve this validation in server side?? ,I have searched quite a bit but am unable to get.I am using apache commons file upload

Comment: you want to validate the file types(.png, .jpeg)?

Comment: What do you want to validate on the server? Mime type? Size? Binary content? What do you already have?

Comment: I want to validate the mime type ,and the extension whether its is jpeg and png or gif and the size too size should be less than 3 mb

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885042/get-file-extension-from-uploaded-file

Comment: No it did'nt help

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have a servlet which implements the servlet specification 3.0, you can use the `@MultipartConfig` annotation with the `maxFileSize` element without using Apache Commons File upload.

1. File size valication:

   ```
   // 10MB
   @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10)
   public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {
   ```

   See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html

   FYI: You need to check the size of a file before uploading it to avoid DoS attacks.
2. File type valication:

   ```
   private boolean isImageFile(String fileName) {
       return Arrays.asList("png", "gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff", "bmp")
           .contains(org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName));
   }
   ```